# Vue.js lib that setAttributes('value', data) on an v-model input

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a JS library that encrypts form data. When submitting the form, it searches for the input with id "adyen_library_data" and sets its attribute 'value' of the encrypted data.

Here's my HTML (inside the #wrapper element) :

```
<form class="ui form" id="adyen-encrypted-form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="hidden" id="adyen_encrypted_data" v-model="input.payment.card.adyen_encrypted_data"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have other fields like card number, CVC, holdername, etc.

My Vue.js script:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#wrapper",
    data: {
        input: {
        payment: {
            card: {
                adyen_encrypted_data: '',
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When the form gets submitted, the "adyen_encrypted_data" changes

before :
[image]

after :[image]

But no way, when I check for `vm.input.payment.card.adyen_encrypted_data` it's empty ! Why ?

Why Vue.js is not responding to `element.setAttribute('value', data)` ? How can I get the value ?

Comment: Where is the code related to `element.setAttribute`?

Comment: @Saurabh it's in the Adyen CSE library. But I do manually the element.setAttribute it's still not binded to the model.